# Youtube subscriber detection

Tags: youtube, subscriber, yt

I can't find any documentation with yt api to fire an event whenever a new user subscribes, but I wonder how people on live streams add new subscriber info on their videos whenever someone subscribes.

I'm trying to get the same youtube subscriber notification like people do when they are in livestreams.

But I can't find any way to do it.

I thought of setting interval of checking channel, like if the sub count increases, check the latest subscriber from subscription list.

But this is kinda complicated and can't handle multiple users when they subscribe.

So my question is how does the youtuber's subscriber notification works and how can I replicate it in a nodejs project for example:

```js
async function newSub(sub){ myWeb.send(user.name+ " Thank you for subscribing"); }
```

Comment: It isn't so difficult and it handles multiple users correctly by enumerating the subscription list until you retrieve all the new subscribers instead of checking only the latest subscriber from subscription list.

Comment: what happens when the subscriber has private sub list. does it just skips the subscriber?

Comment: I think so too.